# Разрешить underscore в ESLint

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, eslint

Нужно разрешить в коде использовать символ нижнего подчёркивания ТОЛЬКО в именах переменных (например, `hello_world`). Как можно это сделать не добавляя `// eslint-disable-next-line camelcase` перед каждой новой переменной?

Comment: eslintrc уже отменили?

Comment: Пробовал добавить `"camelcase": "off"`, но тогда camelcase отключается и для функций

Comment: Ну пропишите список разрешённых имён. Смысл сего желания неясен. Граница между функциями и переменными очень размыта.

Comment: не, прописывать список разрешённых имён точно не вариант) их будет слишком много